# Eeeek! Can't start a bounty on any question

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, javascript, popups

Trying to start a bounty, on any question, results in this:

> [image]

Please fix, in the dev tools I noticed a request to [non existent URL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/bounty/undefined).

This happens in all SE sites as far as I could see.

Comment: @U9-Forward while size does't matter usually, it matters here! lol

Comment: Is this new design change mess up ?

Comment: Lol, yeah it's a bug, that should be fixed, so maybe i should use this term, obvious bug?

Comment: @Shree Yes, i think so too.

Comment: I feel like this could use a bounty for extra attention but....

Comment: @JourneymanGeek no worry in 48 hours I'll totally take screenshot of the bug happening on this question, unless the bug will be fixed before. (Being a weekend, I doubt it but... we can always hope... :-))

Comment: Fixed here on meta, being deployed to the rest of the network right now.

Comment: Our annual [bounta-palooza](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6958/the-third-annual-holiday-bountapalooza/6959#6959) event had quite the scare. :) thanks for wrapping this up quickly all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. It has been fixed across the network now and you should be able to add bounties until your heart is content.

Thanks to [balpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/115866/balpha) who smashed the bug very quickly.

Comment: Maybe it might be worth mentioning that this is fixed also on bug reports on per-site metas. (Although I only found the one [on Mathematics meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29519) when I looked at the [recent posts tagged bounty](https://stackexchange.com/filters/357965/bounty).)

Comment: @Martin Marked as `status-completed` over there. Thanks

Comment: Thanks! *heading towards Wheel of Blame*

Comment: Could you also mark it as `status-completed` [on Workplace meta](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5828/28728)? Thanks!